# MenuFlyoutSeparator doesn't appear in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-runtime, windows-phone, windows-store-apps

a separator line doesn't appear between items, isn't it supported in windows phone version, or I'm doing something wrong?

```
<MenuFlyout>
    <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Like"/>
    <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Report"/>
    <MenuFlyoutSeparator/>
    <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Share"/>
</MenuFlyout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, in Windows Phone 8.1 App, MenuFlyoutSeparator can't appear.
This is MSDN Tip: `In a Windows Phone Store app, MenuFlyoutSeparator is ignored if present in your XAML, and can be removed.` [Here is Url](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn308516.aspx).

Comment: @user3293835 it is back in W10.